# Bootstrap main container wider than rest

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am still new at the whole bootstrap framework, I am loving it but I am looking for some help and guidance. Here is a list of stuff that is going on and I am hoping to get some help.

1. When you come to the site, the first thing issue I have is that the main container and the footer is wider than the menu. With that being said I also have a live feed from our FB page that will not resize according to the screen size.
2. When you resize the screen or view it on a mobile device, and visit the ministries and bylaws, there is a secondary menu that when you select the item it will not auto close.
3. Also on these same pages when there is a hover state, it will go completely across the screen.

I want to thanks everyone in advance on your help. I am also up to suggestions if something is wrong and how to correct it.

The site is www.risenkings.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll have to set a width to your menu so that it is the same as both your main container and footer.  I'm assuming they're either different or the div containing the menu has padding that is keeping the menu from stretching farther to the left and right. It's hard to see without any code.
2. This is poor documentation on Facebook's behalf. When embedding the livefeed, specify the width as `data-width="100%")` as per their documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments.

Also, add this to the end of your last CSS file being linked:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

3. I'm not sure what you mean here. What's the 'it' that you're referring to?

This should get you started to fix those first two points. I need more info to help more than this.

Comment: Sorry "it" I meant to put the hover instead of it. If you look at the code in Chrome would that help with the container and footer issue? Thanks so far I will put what ya got me in place today.